# How to query ERC20 token transfers?

Tags: erc-20

I want to query all in- and outcoming transactions for a given address. To do this I used the etherscanProvider.getHistory method.
However f.e. this address AddrTo = 0x27E28fBc5250668006d82f811174bDC9F147F100 also received a "token transfer" of 5 USDC from address AddrFrom = 0x5E2aFDba5E5F96aed0DcD2760dDE4cFD2aa7b0bA via the smart contract SmartCtr = 0x07865c6e87b9f70255377e024ace6630c1eaa37f (see f.e. https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x27E28fBc5250668006d82f811174bDC9F147F100#tokentxns).

Now when I execute the above getHistory method for the AddrFrom, I get a result (with the to-address being SmartCtr) which is great. But when I do the same for the AddrTo, no such transaction is returned. I would have expected that there is a transaction with SmartCtr being the from-address.

Also if I execute this api: https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x27E28fBc5250668006d82f811174bDC9F147F100&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&page=1&offset=10
I do not get the desired transaction.
Do I need to use some other API or need to go another way?
Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can use API services like Moralis web3api to get the erc20 token transfers. Let me know if you are interested I can show you an example using the Moralis sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the meantime:
One needs to use the contract API as specified in ethers here: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/
Especially the example helped a lot so that my code looks now something like this:

```
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(this.nodeUrl);
    const abi = [
      // Read-Only Functions
      "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
      "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
      "function symbol() view returns (string)",

      // Authenticated Functions
      "function transfer(address to, uint amount) returns (bool)",

      // Events
      "event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount)"
    ];

    // create a contract object
    const erc20 = new ethers.Contract(smartContractAddress, abi, provider);
    try {
      // declare a filter
      const filterAddressTo = erc20.filters.Transfer(null, request.address);
      // apply the filter to get all transactions from the contract to the address
      const ctrResults = await erc20.queryFilter(filterAddressTo, -100000, "latest");
      for (const ctrResult of ctrResults) {
        const transaction = await ctrResult.getTransaction();
      ...
      }
```